# Autoscroll issue when horizontal RecyclerView is placed as an item in a vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

To replicate the problem, I cloned an [existing project](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html) and added two fragments. So now there is an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` which have 2 fragments. Each `Fragment` has a `RecyclerView` (vertical) which contains multiple items of `RecyclerView` (horizontal).

[image]    [image]

Now problem is the autoscroll of vertical `RecyclerView` on switching tab when mid point horizontal `RecyclerView` was left at top.

For example:

1. Page 1 is scrolled to this position

   [image]

(Notice that the first H-Recycler view is set as only half visible)

2. Then tap on PAGE 2 on tablayout to go to the page 2.
3. Now again tap on PAGE 1 on tablayout to go back to the page 1. Here the expected scroll position is where we left earlier but it auto scrolls to the top position. like this[image]

(First `RecyclerView` is full visible instead of half.)

---

I got some clues while figuring out solution.

- This problem occurs with libraries of v24.1.1 and v24.2.1 (latest at the time of writing) but when it is downgraded to v23.4.0 it works as expected. So it's clear that something is modified in library which led to this behaviour.
- Encountered the same problem with an item containing webview. Common thing between webView and H-recyclerView is that both are internally scrollable horizontally. Problem may be related to consumption of scroll event.

Comment: are you calling something on pageVisible event or something?

Comment: No... Nothing is called when user visible hint is changed.

Comment: Hi @HBB20 have u got solution for this problem??

Comment: Well downgrading to version 23.4.0 worked at that time. What is the version number that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the scroll state when the `Fragment` of the `ViewPager` is switching. Lets have a `static` variable in your `Activity` which will store the scroll state like this

```
public static int scrollPositionIndex;
public static int scrollPositionOffset;
```

Now from your `Fragment`, override the `setUserVisibleHint` function.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    // Make sure that we are currently visible
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        // If we are becoming invisible, then...
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {

            // Save scroll state
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            YourActivity.scrollPositionIndex = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            View v = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0);
            YourActivity.scrollPositionOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mRecyclerView.getPaddingTop());

        } else {
            // Scroll to the saved position
            mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(YourActivity.scrollPositionIndex,
                    YourActivity.scrollPositionOffset);

            // Reset the value
            YourActivity.scrollPositionIndex = 0;
            YourActivity.scrollPositionOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but still behaving the same... It auto scrolls..

Comment: What's the problem you're facing here? `setUserVisibleHint` is called or not? Could to save the scrolled position?

Comment: So you need to check if `scrollPositionIndex` and `scrollPositionOffset` is having any value. Check if you're scrolling with the proper `LayoutManager` too.

Comment: I dubug it and confirmed that value is received but behaviour remains same... To fix the issue, for now I have set library version as v23.4.0 and it runs as expected.